# How do I get the details about a Spectrum Scan Error on an external table on Redshift Serverless?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

According to the list of available monitoring views at the bottom of [Monitoring queries and workloads with Amazon Redshift Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-monitoring.html), sys_external_query_error is not available in Redshift Serverless. Which view should I use to see the details about a Spectrum Scan Error on an external table when using Redshift **Serverless**? None of the views listed on that page seem to have the information that I'm looking for.

The view sys_external_query_detail has an error message column, however it just has the text "Spectrum Scan Error" as the message without any useful details.

List of views that I've already tried that aren't available in Redshift Serverless:

- sys_external_query_error
- svl_spectrum_scan_error
- svl_s3log

I was really expecting sys_external_query_error to be available since I'm able to query sys_external_query_detail.